# Are questions about paleoantropology suited for ESSE?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/30039/why-is-autistic-spectrum-disorder-compatible-with-the-schizophrenia-spectrum-in) I thought migth interest neuroscientists, the community from wich I could receive a serious feedback about my theory of autism present in Heidelbergensis (the geological history is in the link, I moved the history to my blog trying to reopen the question).

They closed the question with the geological history but now they have reopened it.

---

I asked then in biology [a related question about my geological history a bit sci-fict, closed too](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113529/is-there-evidence-of-an-evolutionary-strategy-similar-to-human-autism-in-mammals)

I asked also in history for datation of Heildelbergensis travel from Africa to Europe, much more precise, and closed and deleted too.

Then [I went to Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394887/where-to-ask-questions-about-prehistory) to ask why does History site does not answer paleoantropology, where they said biology is the site to my questions about autism and evolution, wich was not my Meta question. Then a biologist said my question was off-topic in biology (but the question is closed as "needs more focus"). Then [I asked in Meta Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4374/77846), where they said my question invites a long discussion.

There is a hole for this topic in Stack Exchange I think, nobody wants to treat it.

---

Not for the autism issue, but for questions as the one closed and deleted in History asking for datation of Heidelbergensis travel from Africa to Europe,

*are paleoantropology questions suited for this site, as being paleontology?*

Answer (score 1):

If your question is something like:

> When did Heidelbergensis travel from Africa to Europe?

Then I don't think it would be on topic here (but I could be wrong). To me it seems perfectly on topic at History SE, as their [help center](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has a mention of "Human Prehistory". The corresponding tag has 82 questions, and yours could fit. I cannot see your deleted question, so I don't know the reasons, but I'd encourage you to try again over there. Maybe you should leave the unnecessary stuff out (like why you're looking for this information), and focus on the question alone.

Answer (score 1):

The only physical/biological trace of autism that we know of is genetic material, so it sounds like you're essentially asking if *H. heidelbergensis* DNA has been recovered and tested for.

That's... a rather narrow cross-section of anthropology, archaeology, and medical biology, none of which are on-topic here. However, there is a medical science and a biology site where it *might* be on-topic, if you phrase it carefully. I don't know if questions asking about the history of medical research is on-topic in either of those sites.

As for your other question here:

> are paleoantropology [sic] questions suited for this site, as being paleontology?

Paleontology itself is on-topic here and has its own tag: [paleontology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleontology). *However*, do note the tag wiki states:

> Paleontology (also Palaeontology) is the scientific study of past life. **Questions about the biological aspect of paleontology (such as taxonomy and anatomy) are off-topic here and should be asked on https://biology.stackexchange.com**

(emphasis mine)

If you are asking about the travel of species from Africa to Europe, that would be on-topic here. If you are asking about the biology or neurology of those species, that would *not* be on-topic here.